# fatal no bootable medium ubuntu virtual machine - unable to click on optical or hard drive

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

I have windows 10 and am trying to have an ubuntu VM. I get the error `fatal no bootable medium`. I went to `settings` and `storage`, but it already shows Host Drive D under `Controller:IDE` and `ubuntuvm.vdi` under `Controller:SATA`. It will not allow me to click to add a new hard drive or optical drive. I also don't have any actual ubuntu CDs with me. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, directly from the [virtualbox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp46856128015632)

> If you have downloaded installation media from the Internet in the form of an ISO image file (most probably in the case of a Linux distribution), you would normally burn this file to an empty CD or DVD and proceed as just described. With VirtualBox however, you can skip this step and mount the ISO file directly. VirtualBox will then present this file as a CD or DVD-ROM drive to the virtual machine, much like it does with virtual hard disk images.
>
> [To] mount the ISO . . . directly [from a file] VirtualBox will . . . present this file as a CD or DVD-ROM drive to the virtual machine, much like it does with virtual hard disk images.
>
> For this case, the wizard's drop-down list contains a list of installation media that were previously used with VirtualBox.
>
> If your medium is not in the list (especially if you are using VirtualBox for the first time), select the small folder icon next to the drop-down list to bring up a standard file dialog, with which you can pick the image file [from the folder containing the downloaded ISO file on your hard-drive].

I would think you would go to hard drive d (if that is where the image is stored) and navigate to the iso file from the drop down menu but I've never ran virtual box on windows, only windows on virtualbox(: